# Cartoon with ginger kid and blonde girl with pigtails traveling to another dimension, accompanied by furry monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There is a cartoon with a ginger boy who is a normal kid, but when a girl with blonde pigtails comes into his room they travel to another dimension. There are episodes with pistachio ice cream and giant vending machines. They are usually a good accompanied by two furry monsters.

I saw it on YTV or Teletoon in Canada. I believe it was at least a few seasons in length. I watched it in the mid 2000s. I know it is not Lloyd in Space or Chalkzone.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when would it have been aired?

Comment: Also, was this an anime style cartoon or a US/European style cartoon? Was it a long or short series? Where did you see it (country, channel)?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I saw it in Canada, most likely YTV or Teletoon. I believe it was a moderately long series (a few seasons). I believe it was a US styled cartoon.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that I've never had the chance to watch it, but it could be [Magical Shopping Arcade Abenobashi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/306/Abenobashi_Mahou%E2%98%86Shoutengai), an anime by Gainax.

I know it has a weird, humorous plot with different dimensions and one of the protagonists is a girl with pigtails (even if she's not blonde)

[image]

Comment: Does it have the furry monster companions?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Honestly, I don't know if there are any furry monsters... but usually every episode was a kind of parody of a film/anime genre, so there could be some furry monsters, maybe only in one or two episodes